# Cutting down a list based on events being in between two datetimes

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I have a list of object that, among other bits of data, include a date, and I need to create a list of all the objects where that date falls anytime last month, i.e. midnight on the 1st of last month < target data < midnight on the 1st of this month.

I also need the number of total objects that meet this criteria.

Right now, I'm going about it in a series of while loops, but I feel like there has to be a better way, particularly since my script hangs:

```
        post = 0 #the current post we're analyzing
        posts = 0 #the total number of posts in the month we actually care about
        lastmonthposts = [] #I think i can just get rid of this
        blog = pyblog.WordPress()

        date = blog.get_recent_posts(1 + posts)[0]['dateCreated']
        while (date > startthismonth):
            print "So far, there have been " + str(posts) + " posts this month we've counted."
            post = post + 1
            date = blog.get_recent_posts(1 + post)[0]['dateCreated']
        while (date > startlastmonth):
            print "So far, there have been " + str(posts) + " posts last month we've counted, which is " + str(date.timetuple().tm_mon) + "."
            posts = posts + 1
            post = post + 1
            date = blog.get_recent_posts(1 + post)[0]['dateCreated']
            lastmonthposts.append('blog')
        for blogpost in lastmonthposts:
            postnumber = blogpost['postid']
            comments = comments + int(blog.get_comment_count(postnumber)['approved'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `get_recent_posts()` I would use `get_page_list()`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

this_month_start = datetime.now().date().replace(day=1)
prev_month_start = (this_month_start - timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1)

pages = blog.get_page_list()
last_month_pages = [
  p for p in pages
  if prev_month_start <= p['dateCreated'] < this_month_start]
last_month_approved_comment_count = sum(
  blog.get_comment_count(page['page_id'])['approved']
  for page in last_month_pages)

print "number of last month's pages:", len(last_month_pages)
print "number of approved comments for last month's pages:",
print last_month_approved_comment_count
```

Comment: Thanks Constantin, this is definitely much simpler. I don't understand why you suggest get_page_list() though, which seems to just return "0" since while there are new blog posts, there are no new pages. Working to reconfigure it to work with posts and then I'll mark you accepted.

Comment: @Michael Morisy, Hmm, I was under impression that "post" and "page" meant the same thing in the API. Is that a wrong assumption? Are you sure `blog.get_page_list()` returns "0"? Could you insert `print pages` after `pages = blog.get_page_list()` and check the output?

Comment: Thanks so much for checking back. No, posts and pages are handled differently in WP. I double checked with your print suggestion, and it printed the about page. Replacing that with <code>pages = blog.get_recent_posts()</code>, however, prints out the material I want to look at, but I still get all 0s even though that print command prints out the right post. Going to check and see if I'm looking at the date wrong.

Comment: OK, figured out the problem. It's comparing two different time formats, 2010-11-01 vs. 20100326T06:52:17. Thanks for all the help @Constantin.